# Spring Rest and Jsonp

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, jsonp

I am trying to get my Spring rest controller to return **jsonp** but I am having no joy

The exact same code works ok if I want to return json but I have a requirement to return **jsonp**
I have added in a converter I found source code for online for performing the jsonp conversion

I am using Spring version 4.1.1.RELEASE and Java 7

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is the code in question

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


  <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
       <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
       <property name="parameterName" value="mediaType" />
       <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false"/>
       <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
       <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />

       <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="atom"  value="application/atom+xml" />
                <entry key="html"  value="text/html" />
                <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript" />
                <entry key="json"  value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml"   value="application/xml"/>
            </map>
        </property>
  </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager" />
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/slim/${views.template.directory}/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.webapp.handler.MappingJacksonJsonpView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**com.webapp.handler.MappingJacksonJsonpView**

```
package com.webapp.handler;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;

public class MappingJacksonJsonpView extends MappingJackson2JsonView {
    /** Local log variable. **/
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MappingJacksonJsonpView.class);

    /**
     * Default content type. Overridable as bean property.
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/javascript";

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the view given the specified model, merging it with static
     * attributes and a RequestContext attribute, if necessary.
     * Delegates to renderMergedOutputModel for the actual rendering.
     * @see #renderMergedOutputModel
     */
    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Entered render Method :{}", request.getMethod());

        if("GET".equals(request.getMethod().toUpperCase())) {
            LOG.info("Request Method is a GET call");

            Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

            if(params.containsKey("callback")) {
                String callbackParam = params.get("callback")[0];
                LOG.info("callbackParam:{}", callbackParam);
                response.getOutputStream().write(new String(callbackParam + "(").getBytes());
                super.render(model, request, response);
                response.getOutputStream().write(new String(");").getBytes());
                response.setContentType(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
            }
            else {
                LOG.info("Callback Param not contained in request");
                super.render(model, request, response);
            }
        }

        else {
            LOG.info("Request Method is NOT a GET call");
            super.render(model, request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Method In Question**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/sources"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces={MediaType.ALL_VALUE,
        "text/javascript",
        "application/javascript",
        "application/ecmascript",
        "application/x-ecmascript",
        "application/x-javascript", 
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public Object getSources(@PathVariable(value = API_KEY) String apiKey, 
        @RequestParam(value = "searchTerm", required = true) String searchTerm,
        @RequestParam(value = "callBack", required = false) String callBack) {
    LOG.info("Entered getSources - searchTerm:{}, callBack:{} ", searchTerm, callBack);

    List<SearchVO> searchVOList = myServices.findSources(searchTerm);

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(searchVOList)) {
        LOG.error("No results exist for the searchterm of {}", searchTerm);
        return searchVOList;
    }         

    LOG.debug("{} result(s) exist for the searchterm of {}", searchVOList.size(), searchTerm);        

    LOG.info("Exiting getSources");
    return searchVOList;
}
```

**Jquery Ajax Code **

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/my-web/rest/sources,
                data: {
                    "searchTerm": request.term
                },
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                 success: function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Failure");
                }
            });
```

A snippet of the error stacktrace that I get is as follows

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:198) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
```

Comment: Did not read all your code, but in the javascript, you have missed the closing bracket and semi-colon in the ajax `success` method: `alert("success"` should be `alert("success");`

Comment: @Ivaylyo - Sorry that is updated now - I had to change some code prior to putting it online for privacy reasons - good spot

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never done JSONP with Spring, but as far as I am familiar with JSONP, it needs a callback function to pass the result to. This would not be the same as the `success` ajax handler. The jQuery ajax request supports a `jsonpCallback` parameter, that should be the name of the callback function. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.iceycake.com/2012/06/xml-json-jsonp-web-service-endpoints-spring-3-1/) for reference, I hope this helps you solve the issue

Comment: A second read on your issue suggests that you might need to configure a coverter for the JSONP (application/javascript) data type withing the spring controller configuration. The `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` usually indicates that spring does not find a suitable converter for the supplied data type that is present in the request.

Comment: @Ivaylo - I have a converted written - its called MappingJacksonJsonpView  and attached in the message. The jquery callback will not be a problem if it isworking but I am getting no response back from the server. The converter is being access on the server and then the exception is being thrown

Comment: OK, it must be me, since I am not exactly familiar with the view mappers. As you debug into the `MappingJacksonJsonpView`, do you get inside the `if(params.containsKey("callback")) { ...` clause. If somehow the converter does not get the callback parameter, it would probably fallback to the `MappingJackson2JsonView`'s behavior (`else { super.render(...)`, and my wild guess is that it will fail, because the jackson converter would actually expect `applicatio/json` as content type (and probably validates it in the `render` method).

Comment: Is application/javascript or application/ecmascript better to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated on the spring.io [blog](http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements) regarding the Spring 4.1 release:

> JSONP is now supported with Jackson. For response body methods declare
>   an @ControllerAdvice as shown below. For View-based rendering simply
>   configure the JSONP query parameter name(s) on
>   [MappingJackson2JsonView](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJackson2JsonView.java#L174-L176).

```
@ControllerAdvice
private static class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }

}
```

> [...] In 4.1 an @ControllerAdvice can also implement
>   ResponseBodyAdvice in which case it will be called after the
>   controller method returns but before the response is written and
>   therefore committed. This has a number of useful applications with
>   @JsonView the JSONP already serving as two examples built on it.

Javadoc taken from [MappingJackson2JsonView](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJackson2JsonView.java#L174-L176):

> Set JSONP request parameter names. Each time a request has one of those
>   parameters, the resulting JSON will be wrapped into a function named as
>   specified by the JSONP request parameter value.
>   The parameter names configured by default are "jsonp" and "callback".

You don't need to implement this stuff by yourself. Just reuse the bits from the Spring Framework.

### Spring Boot example

Following simple Spring Boot application demonstrates use of build in JSONP support in Spring MVC 4.1.
Example requires at least Spring Boot 1.2.0.RC1.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice;

import java.util.Collections;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = ANY)
    static class MyBean {
        String attr = "demo";
    }

    @ControllerAdvice
    static class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
        public JsonpAdvice() {
            super("callback");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(false, Collections.<HttpMessageConverter<?> >singleton(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()));
    }

    @RequestMapping
    MyBean demo() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @RequestMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String demo2() {
        return "demo2";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

URL `http://localhost:8080/demo?callback=test` converts a POJO into a `JSONP` response:

```
test({"attr":"demo"});
```

URL `http://localhost:8080/demo2?callback=test` converts a `String` into a `JSONP` response:

```
test("demo2");
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me at this  I wasnt aware of this update in Spring 4.1

Comment: ksokol - I have tried this solution but I am still not experiencing any joy. Do you know if any of the spring sample applications are utilizing this jsonp functionality currently?

Comment: First, try to access your endpoint via browser without your javascript client e.g. `http://localhost:8080/demo?callback=test`. Do you receive a jsonp response then?
In your jQuery snippet replace `contentType: "application/javascript"` with `dataType: "jsonp"`.

Comment: tried both those suggestions - still get the exact same error in the stacktrace - org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Did you removed your custom `MappingJacksonJsonpView` before using Spring's solution? Could you strip down your configuration and controller to a bare minimum and test again?

Comment: I did indeed but still no joy at all with both options - still the same error message

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @ksokol - i started a new dummy application and it is working as expected. I  wil ltrawl through my existing app now and change as necessary to get it going - thanks again

Comment: Thanks. I found more information in the spring blogs

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements