# Spring Rest and JSONP conversion error

Tags: java, spring, rest, jsonp

I'm trying to convert my response to JSONP for all my spring REST APIs. I tried as given in the below URL:

[Spring Rest and Jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974835/spring-rest-and-jsonp/35579467#35579467)

JSONP gets generated for custom beans(eg: Employee Bean). But not for string and int(primitive types). Should I add any other dependency or should I check all the request data types and apply the conversion?

eg. URL http://localhost:8080/demo2?callback=test should return test("demo2") but returns only demo2.

http://localhost:8080/demo?callback=test returns correctly test({"attr":"demo"});

Also, if I accept int from URL and return the same, JSONP is generated. But not for the int set inside the method.

Not working: localhost:8080/demo2?callback=test

```
@RequestMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Integer demo2() {
    int i=3;
    return i;
}
```

Throws error: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers. Working: localhost:8080/demo2/3?callback=test

```
 @RequestMapping(value="test/{a}" produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Integer demo2 (@PathVariable("a")int a)
{
       return a;
}
```

test(3);

Comment: Please explain something which is logical.. actually i didn't get you what you trying to say..  u have mentioned two `code` but didn't defined what you exactly want to achieve?? totally jumble..

Comment: My question is in regards/continuation to the URL that I posted at the beginning. If you don't read it, u can't understand my question and obviously it will look jumbled and it won't look logical from your perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{a}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Integer demo2(@PathVariable("a") int a) {
    return a;
}
```

And make sure you have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In your pom.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's there in my pom. I tried your suggestion. I get the same "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers." error message.

Comment: Hi, This method will work fine which I have mentioned in my question as "working". But this approach below throws error. @RequestMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Integer demo2() {
    int i=3;
    return i;
}

Comment: There is no URL mapping on that method??

Comment: Everything is there. My actual code: @RequestMapping(value="/Test5.html", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<Integer> getTest5(){ 
  Integer a=6; 
  return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(a);  
 }

Comment: Another code which also doesn't work: @RequestMapping(value="/Test3.html", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 @ResponseBody int getTest3(){ 
  int a=9;
  return a;  
 }